# Automatically generate check in comments in TFS 2010

Tags: comments, checkin

I'm currently trying to eliminate the need for check in comments in TFS 2010 as the information about each change we make is already documented within an associated work item.  The only issue with this is when you look at the file change history, the "Comments" column is blank thus making it difficult to find the change you are looking for.

To resolve this we enter the name of the work item in the check in comments but I am wondering if there is a way that I can have TFS automatically do this.

For example:
If I have a Change Request work item called "Add New Feature 1" and I check in the changes against this, I would like the check in comments to automatically have "Add New Feature 1" included in them.

Anyone know if this is possible and if so how I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to either write a Server Plugin or maybe a policy (not sure if policies can change the checkin comment though).

Checkout the following plugin which associates workitems based on the checkin comment.
http://embeddedworkitems.codeplex.com/  It's the reverse of what you want but should be adaptable.

Comment: I don't think a policy has this much control but certainly the server plugin option works nicely.  I managed to write a simple event handler from the example posted so thanks very much for that.

Comment: @Gavimoss can you provide some detais on how to accomplish that?